# numpy fill 3D mask array from 2D k-index boundary array

Tags: numpy, indexing

I want to use a 2D array which contains k-index values to *quickly* fill a 3D array with different mask values above/below each k-index.  Only non-zero boundary indices will be used to fill.

Initialize 2D k-index array and extract valid i-j index arrays:

```
import numpy as np
boundary_indices = np.array([[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [0, 2, 0]])
ii, jj = np.where(boundary_indices > 0)  # determine desired indices
kk = boundary_indices[ii, jj]  # align boundary indices with valid indices
```

Yields:

```
boundary_indices = array([[0, 1, 2],
                          [1, 2, 1],
                          [0, 2, 0]])
ii = array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])
jj = array([1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1])
kk = array([1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])
```

Loop through the indices and populate the output array:

```
output = np.zeros((3, 3, 3), dtype=np.int64)
for i, j, k in zip(ii, jj, kk):
    output[i, j, :k] = 7  # fill region above
    output[i, j, k:] = 8  # fill region below
```

While this does yield the correct results, it becomes quite slow once the size of the array increases significantly:

```
output[:, :, 0] = [[0, 7, 7],
                   [7, 7, 7],
                   [0, 7, 0]]
output[:, :, 1] = [[0, 8, 7],
                   [8, 7, 8],
                   [0, 7, 0]]
output[:, :, 2] = [[0, 8, 8],
                   [8, 8, 8],
                   [0, 8, 0]]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

---

Tried `output[ii, jj, kk] = 8` but that only imprints the boundary on the output array and not the regions above/below.

I was hoping that there would be some fancy-indexing magic and that something like this would work:

```
output[ii, jj, :kk] = 7
output[ii, jj, kk:] = 8
```

But it generates a TypeError: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`

Answer (score 0):

For such kind of operation, **Numba** and Cython can be used to produce an efficient code. Here is an example with Numba:

```py
import numba as nb

# `parallel=True` can be added here for large arrays
@nb.njit('int64[:,:,::1](int64[:], int64[:], int64[:])')
def compute(ii, jj, kk):
    output = np.zeros((3, 3, 3), dtype=np.int64)
    n = output.shape[2]
    # `for idx in prange(ii.size)` can be used here for large array
    for i, j, k in zip(ii, jj, kk):
        # `i, j, k = ii[idx], jj[idx], kk[idx]` can be used here for large array
        for l in range(k):           # fill region above
            output[i, j, l] = 7
        for l in range(k, n):        # fill region below
            output[i, j, l] = 8
    return output

# Either kk needs to be converted to an int64-based array with kk.astype(np.int64)
# or boundary_indices needs to be an int64-based array in the first place.
output = compute(ii, jj, kk)
```

Note that the Numba function can be faster if `ii` and `jj` are contiguous. However, they are surprisingly not contiguous when retrieved from `np.where`. Besides I assume that `kk` is a 64-bit array. You can change the signature (string in the Numba jit decorator) so to support 32-bit array. Also please note that Numba can lazily compile the function based on the provided type at runtime but this introduce a significant overhead during the first function call. This code is significantly faster, especially for large arrays thanks to the the [just-in-time compilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) of Numba. The Numba loop can be **parallelized** using `prange` and the `parallel=True` decorator flag although the current code should already be pretty good. Finally, note that you can do the operation `np.where(boundary_indices > 0)` directly in the Numba loop on the fly so to avoid creating possibly-expensive temporary arrays.